# Bubble sort of an array with n numbers with Theta(n*sqrt(n)) swaps

Tags: arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

How can i construct an array with n numbers that needs Theta(n*sqrt(n)) swaps? I no the worst case for Bubble needs (n^2-n)/2 swaps is when the array is sorted in the wrong direction. Maybe it's possible when a part of the array is sorted and the other par is sorted in the wrong direction ?